# Identify $\frac{1}{x+y}$ operator

Tags: analysis

Good evening!

I'm just here to ask a quick question. 
I was watching an analysis lecture which mentioned an operator $K$, from $L^{2}(0,+\infty)$ to itself, defined as followed:

$$K : f \mapsto \left(x \mapsto \displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x+y} f(y) \text{ d}y \right)$$

The lecturer said it was famous, and referred to it as **the** Hankel operator, and I could not find any mention of it in articles I found about the subject.

All I wanted to know is the name of this operator, should it have one; so if anyone heard any mention of it, I'd be grateful. Thanks :)

Comment: It's the Laplace transform of the Laplace transform of $f$.

Comment: Hi, excuse me, I don't quite see the relation with the Laplace transform? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit out of training, but I am not sure that what you have here is a Hankel operator in $L^2(0,\infty)$. You can follow the definition in [Proposition 4.1](https://books.google.se/books?id=bG03AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=L2+hankel+integral&source=bl&ots=u6s4RezU8z&sig=ACfU3U1c9VVCr-1Enq_7CJXKDHEBqsLhwQ&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBjpOZyMHiAhXDpYsKHcF2B5cQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=L2%20hankel%20integral&f=false) and see that, for that to be the Hankel operator, we need $h(x) =1/x$, which is not in $L^2(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for the source :) So I guess it should be a Hankel operator on $L^2(1,+\infty)$ at least

Comment: That is indeed an option, I don't want to say it for sure is because there may be hidden steps in the proposition that rely on it being $(0,\infty)$. You need to be a bit careful :)

Comment: I will be, thanks for your answer :)